# How could I allow users to access to my google cloud storage

Tags: android, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I'm developing an android application. 
In the android application, users read files from my google cloud storage and also update files to it, although it is not the main purpose of the application.
Now, I'm quite confused about how I allow users access to my google cloud storage.
Google recommends to use OAutn 2.0 authentication. So, I treid how it works on the following site.
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

In the playground, I allowed the "oauthplayground" to access to my google cloud storage. 
But I don't need this step because I always want to allow the android application to access to my google cloud storage. 
After thinking, I had the idea to use the Authorization code for the android application to access to my google cloud storage.
But it was a bad idea because an Authorization code has the expiration time.

How  I allow users to access to my google cloud storage in this case??
Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If privacy is not a concern, you could set the ACL on the bucket to public-write. If privacy is a concern, you can use the [Signed URLs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs) feature. You can find an example of using the Signed URLs feature in the [storage-signedurls-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python) repository on GitHub.

Comment: The signed URLs feature is exactly what I have been looking for!! Thank you so much!!